# want to avoid Keyboard cover in TextFormField like Native android and IOS

Tags: flutter

I'm first developing mobile on flutter, So I have problem with keyboard. when I type on TextFormField, the keyboard alway cover. So I want ask how to avoid Keyboard cover.

Comment: Switch to `dev` channel `flutter channel dev`. This is an issue that should have been fixed recently.